# Maintain expected requirements when moving from createdb command to CREATE DATABASE command

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm on a Windows laptop and tried to run the following command using my SQL shell (PSQL) and command prompt line:

```
$ createdb -U postgres -w address-bloc-dev
```

but I got this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createdb"

I tried then to use the `CREATE DATABASE` SQL command, and it worked. However, I would like to still specify Postgres as User and avoid requesting a password to access the database I'm creating.

What are the SQL commands that I should use to achieve this objective?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: `createdb` is a command line program, **not** a SQL statement. Inside `psql` you need to use [create database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, I did it. But it is not enough. I would like to replicate the whole command line, so also specify the user postgres (-U postgres) and avoid requesting a password (-w), along with the CREATE DATABASE SQL statement

Comment: You clearly did not use `CREATE DATABASE` in the code you showed in your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry for the misunderstanding. You can read in the text below the yellow error that I also said that I tried to use the CREATE DATABASE command and that it worked. But I still don't know how to specify the user and make it password free

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I run the command CREATE DATABASE -U postgres -w address-bloc-dev, it doesn't work

Comment: Please read [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) - the complete syntax is explained there